# Import an Azure DevOps repository

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2019

In an Azure DevOps (version 2019.1) project I want to import a git repository from another project of the same server. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/import-git-repository?view=azure-devops) seems to be quite straight forward on this point. So I used the clone URL from the source repo, went to to the target project (menu item: *Repos*) and tried to start the import.

However the import fails with the following error message:

```
Import request cannot be processed due to one of the following reasons:
Clone URL is incorrect.
Clone URL requires authorization.
Clone URL points to an empty repository.
```

Regarding these reasons I can only add that the URL is not incorrect because I've worked with that repository already and have comitted files and pushed changes. That means the repo isn't empty either. The URL doesn't require any authorization because I can clone the repo without giving any credentials.

Is there anything else that I may be missing? Do I need to create an empty repo on the target project first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this issue , I tested the same scenario in azure devops 2019.I got the same error without using PAT authentication:

[image]

After using PAT for authentication, the repo can be imported into other project in the server normally. You can try to use PAT to authenticate and see if it works.

Comment: I am getting in the same issue.  What if I import the porjec to Azure devops and then doing cotinious integration and created brach and other stuff. What if the PAT valid for 7 days. Will I still be able to check in , create branches etc?