# Azure Devops, import Git Repository

Tags: git, azure, repository, devops

I am unable to import a git repository into Azure Devops.  I have the correct url and username/password entries, but I get the error message - Clone URL is incorrect and/or
Clone URL requires authorization.

[image: I am unable to import a git repository into Azure Devops. I have the correct url and username/password entries, but I get the error message - Clone URL is incorrect and/or Clone URL requires authorization.]

Comment: You have redacted everything we could have used to help you - like the clone URL...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import an Azure DevOps repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60986988/import-an-azure-devops-repository)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['Clone URL is incorrect' when importing from GitHub to Azure DevOps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60321498/clone-url-is-incorrect-when-importing-from-github-to-azure-devops)

Comment: You could try to manually import the repo using the CLI. At the very least you might get a better error message to help track down the issue. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/import-git-repository?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to get a repo from this URL (https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/pipelines-dotnet-core). but it gets an error as you show in question.

[image]

After removing all space and the last dot (https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/pipelines-dotnet-core) from the URL it's working fine. You check whether again URL is correct or not. may it contain some additional char in URL.

[image]

[image]